# After running apt-get or yum install, how do you find out where the newly installed package is?

Tags: installation, yum, apt, package-management

How do you find out where your package has been installed? More importantly, where are the setting files for it (for instance, httpd.conf with Apache, or php.ini with PHP)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dpkg -L <packetname>
```

on debian etc. and

```
rpm -ql <packetname>
```

on rpm based distributions (redhat, suse, centos)

The settings files will usually be located somewhere below /etc.